# Помогите достать имя файла без расширения PHP

Tags: php

Мой код, здесь копируется название файла полностью

```
$textname= basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo $textname;
```

Помогите сделать копию имени файла без расширения

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183486/php-get-file-name-without-file-extension

Comment: Пример 1. Пример использования функции basename()

<?php
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file содержит "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file содержит "index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать стандартную функцию `pathinfo()` и обратиться к элементу массива `filename` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php))

Таким образом ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
$textname= basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$pathInfo = pathinfo($textname);
echo $pathInfo["filename"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать функцию rtrim():

```
$filenameonly = rtrim($yourfilename,'.mp4');
```

Вместо '.mp4' можно поставить любое расширение.
А еще есть функция pathinfo(), которая возвращает массив с информацией о пути. Если путь является файлом, то в массиве с ключом ['filename'] будет имя файла без расширения.

```
$array = pathinfo($path);
```

Comment: вы неправильно понимаете работу фунции trim(). Это расхожее заблуждение, но в любом случае непростительное. echo rtrim('stomp.mp4','.mp4');

Comment: По-моему, я все правильно понимаю: функция rtrim() обрезает строку справа по конкретной последовательности символов.

Comment: [Убедитесь](https://3v4l.org/ugHdI)

Comment: Все ясно, спасибо. В тамком случае, на место rtrim() подойдет функция substr().